# Theme not uploading showing maximum upload size on live site

Tags: theme-development

I have developed on theme which have integrated framework for theme options, visual composer and slider, it make the theme size nearly 11mb after compressed(zip) but while i want to upload the theme by wp-admin area it provides the upload error but if upload using ftp(live site) it works. How can i make the upload from admin area on live site? (The integration are compulsory on theme)

Comment: If you intend to sell the theme to other people then you should assume that you can't.

Answer (score 0):

You should increase `upload_max_filesize` in your `php.ini` file. If you use cPanel based control panel,  you can create file called `php.ini` in your public_html dir, and put `upload_max_filesize = 15M` there.

Other way it to tell your hosting provider to increase your max upload limit.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider including a server test plugin with your theme and when it detects that the theme cannot be uploaded via web interface then it should alert the user so they can contact their hosting provider to update the php values.